# Python 3 - why use self here?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am currently reading "Creating GUI Applications with wxPython".

I understand self is used to refer to an instance of an object that has been created from a class but why is it used here on : `self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)` and on other objects within the layout method? If you take out the prepended `self.` from the objects the code still works.

```
class ImagePanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.max_size = 240
        self.photos = []
        self.layout()

    def layout(self):
        """
        Layout the widgets on the panel
        """
        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btn_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        img = wx.Image(self.max_size, self.max_size)
        self.image_ctrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                          wx.Bitmap(img))
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.image_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.image_label = wx.StaticText(self, label="")
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.image_label, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)

        btn_data = [("Previous", btn_sizer, self.on_previous),
                    ("Slide Show", btn_sizer, self.on_slideshow),
                    ("Next", btn_sizer, self.on_next)]
        for data in btn_data:
            label, sizer, handler = data
            self.btn_builder(label, sizer, handler)

        self.main_sizer.Add(btn_sizer, 0, wx.CENTER)
        self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)
```

Comment: If you only reference those items within that single definition (`def layout`) there is no need to add them as members of `self`. The issue can arise later, if you find that you do want to change something. Many simply slap the `self` on there just in case but if you know it's a one off thing, feel free to leave it off.

Answer (score 0):

While this example doesn't show it, normally you would initialize the layout in **init**(). Then you would need to use self to be able to add the widgets to the layout in your layout() method.

The other big use case is when you need to add or remove widgets after creating your initial user interface. In that case, you also need to have the layout object prepended with self.